# Domino 11 and CAPTCHA

Tags: xpages, captcha, lotus-domino

We are in process of upgrading our servers to Windows 19 and Domino 11.0.1. Before we were on Windows 2008 and Domino 9.0.1. We have a page that requires Captcha answer to continue and works on Windows 2008 and Domino 9.0.1 as well as Windows 19 and Domino 9.0.1 but when we upgarded to Domino 11.0.1 on Windows 2019 it stopped working. What happens is when all pictures are selected and user clicks Continue, the error message that states "Please check off "I'm not a robot above." and you have to start Captcha process again. It never allows one to go forward.

Any ideas as to where I might find solution to this challenge.

Comment: There is no built in captcha in any domino version. So you must have gotten it from somewhere and implemented... you need to ask the creator of the captcha what is going on. Nobody with Domino knowledge can answer this unless he incidentially used the same captcha and found the incompatibility... most probably it is a problem with java versions as Domino 11 updated to newer Java from 1.6 that what used in 9.0.1 (prior FP8)

Comment: Yes it was taken from a openntf recaptcha project.  Trying to debug it more now.

Comment: and that project is using google recapcha on an xpage so it could be an issue with the java upgrade but then you would see the same issue with 9.01fp8 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was an internet certification issue on the Domino side which we finally resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to build Internal Captcha for Notes Domino Applications.

Here is the sample:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6udCknA1D4A&t=19s